# How to rectify the gap between line numbers and code in WebStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

[How to rectify the gap between line numbers and code in web storm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3X62f.png)

[There is a huge gap between the line numbers and the code in webstorm Ide. The theme that I am using is Material Theme-darker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3X62f.png)

Comment: Are you in some sort of Full Screen or Presentation mode? Of so -- quit it.

Comment: View | Exit Distraction Free Mode.

Comment: Any solutions to this? It would be good to have it in Zen mode?